# Корректная оплата в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем доброго времени суток.

Выполняю заказ, и требуется подключить оплату, но я никогда ранее не подключал ее. В интернете очень мало информации, а задача довольно важная и ответственная.  Использую `liqpay`. Что я упустил при ее подключении, или этого достаточно для корректной оплаты? А если будет ошибка оплаты, но указан параметр `ok=True` - появится окно с `error_message`? На практике мне не удалось вызвать такую ошибку.

```
# здесь подключение к базе данных и извлечение данных
bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id,
                 title='Покупка товара',
                 description=f'Покупка товара: {title[0]},
                 invoice_payload='something_text_for_invoice',
                 provider_token='provider_token',
                 start_parameter='buy_product',
                 currency='uah',
                 prices=[LabeledPrice(label='Текст', amount=int(price[0]))])
```

```
@bot.pre_checkout_query_handler(func=lambda query: True)
def checkout(pre_checkout_query):
    bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True, 
                                  error_message="Оплата не прошла - попробуйте, пожалуйста, еще раз,"
                                                "или свяжитесь с администратором бота.")


# при корректной оплате
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['successful_payment'])
def got_payment(message):

    # здесь подключение к базе данных и внесение данных в таблицу
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваш заказ был успешным❤')
```

Comment: вы можете использовать тестовые карты для проверки сценариев оплаты. например https://securepayments.sberbank.ru/wiki/doku.php/test_cards

Comment: @Violet, я пробовал подключать и оплачивать тестовый вариант, но тестировал всего пол дня. Реального опыта у меня нет, и я не знаю, может ли вызвать подобный код, который я привел - ошибки? Возможно, есть какие-то подводные камни, если вы подключали такую оплату.

Comment: если вы руководствовались https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py то не должно возникнуть проблем. я реализовывал на Я.Деньги, в тестах и первых боевых оплатах не выявлено ошибок.

Comment: @Violet, понял. Да, руководствовался этим кодом. Спасибо за советы:)