# Подскажите, как создать Invoice на wayforpay в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, webhook

Не могу понять, как сделать invoice, который будет отправлять бот в телеграмме.
Бот на webhook`е.

Comment: Как для `wayforpay` - не знаю, кажется тг в  Украине поддерживает только `liqpay` и `tranzzo`, другие `invoice` как я понимаю перенаправляют юзера в браузер. Я ранее задавал здесь подобный вопрос - пример с `invoice` можете посмотреть здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1241045/Корректная-оплата-в-telebot

Comment: @DeNRuDi я делаю через API